# Apply "INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" rules for All INSERTS made against table?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, duplicates, primary-key

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sources` (
  `domain`            VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
  `data`             VARCHAT(255)
)
```

Can I qualify this table so that anytime someone tries to `INSERT` a duplicate `domain` value, we would update the record rather than throw an error? Basically, I want all my INSERTS to be INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE for this table.

Comment: No, you must specify `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in every `INSERT` statement.  If you are allowing your users to execute arbitrary SQL on your database, then you're almost certainly going about things the wrong way: at very least, consider inserting a proxy layer to authenticate/log/audit/transform their actions (you could then inject `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` into their `INSERT` commands if so desired).